# Copy several Slack chat messages without timestamps or users

Tags: slack, copy-paste

If I try copying and pasting several Slack chat messages, I usually end up with lots of extra lines that are empty, or have a timestamp, or have a username and a timestamp.

Is there any way to just get the messages themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. But you could make use of a clipboard manager app, and then individually copy all the messages one by one. The clipboard manager app should be able to store all the messages separately, and then later you can paste them where you want.

[Maccy](https://maccy.app/) or [CopyClip](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/copyclip-clipboard-history/id595191960?mt=12) are a couple of examples of clipboard managers for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Online free tool: https://www.mattzeunert.com/slack-paste.html

Unsure of privacy implications